# How to prove Duhamel's integral using the method of Variation of Parameters?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, parabolic-pde

Given the following IBVP.
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{x} \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}$$

Initial condition
$$T(x,t=0)=0$$

BCs.

$$T(x=0,t)=1$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} T(x,t)=0$$

How to prove using the method of Variation of Parameters that the following solution

$$y(x,t) = g(t)*\frac{\partial }{\partial t}T(t) = \int_{0}^{t} g(t - \tau)\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau} T(\tau) d\tau$$

Solves the following IBVP?

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{x} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$$

Initial condition
$$y(x,t=0)=0$$

BCs.

$$y(x=0,t)=g
(t)$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} y(x,t)=0$$

Comment: Why did you write the problem twice?

Comment: I think I didn't. The inner boundary condition for both is different. In the first problem, IBC is constant and in the second one, the IBC is time dependent. @K.defaoite

Comment: Oh I see now. My mistake, apologies.